# Cannot access windows partiton from live USB

Tags: mount, fdisk

I am having problems with a windows machine (for work). The problems are bizarre - i can't get past the splash screen, however some of the startup interrupt options work, as long as i wait a very long time.

The aim here is that I want to get the content off my windows ssd. I am a linux user for my personal computing. Thus i thought i could make a live USB boot to that, get the data off the windows partition and then send the machine for repairs.

Problem is i cannot access the windows parition from the live USB.

If i run: `sudo fdisk -l`, i get:
Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type

```
/dev/sdb1  *          0 4812191 4812192  2.3G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       4073124 4081059    7936  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3       4812800 7835647 3022848  1.5G 83 Linux
```

The `Empty` record under `Type` has me worried, but i don't know much about this stuff.

Anyway, i try mounting with: `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /~/windows`

But i get:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

It is also notable that i cannot see the windows partition in GParted.

Obviously if this is simply a problem with my windows partition, i don't expect answers here. That said, if the windows partition is working and anyone can help me access to it from my live instance of ubuntu linux, i would be extremely grateful.

Comment: It looks like `/dev/sdb` is your USB drive. Please add information about `/dev/sda`, which may be the drive with Windows. Windows in fast start mode (the default) does not shut down it's system drives properly. This may appear to be "dirty" drive to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think i can turn off fast start. I can't get into the windows partition, and the bios freezes when i try and navigate past security (part of the extremely bizarre behavior on the machine). I understand if there are no other solutions. This was a long shot.

Comment: @MorrisseyJ can you post the output of lsblk? /dev/sdb1 is not your windows partition and hence you are not able to mount it.

Comment: @ignite Thanks very much for coming back to me. Having been stumped by this I have already had to return the machine and don't have it with me anymore.